# Finding p.m.f. of a geometric distribution for discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Define 2 independent geometric variables

- X the number of days until Lily sends you a letter, with an average waiting time of $1/\lambda$ days $(0 < \lambda < 1, X ≥ 1)$
- Y the number of days until Noah sends you a letter, with an average waiting time of $1/\mu$ days $(0 < \mu < 1, Y ≥ 1)$

Let D be the time before either sends you a letter.

1. What is the cumulative distribution function of D?
2. Derive the p.m.f. of I defined by
   \begin{equation}
   I=
   \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{if Lily's letter arrives strictly before Noah's}\\
   1 & \text{if both letters arrive on the same day}\\
   2 & \text{if Lily's letter arrives strictly after Noah's}
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
3. Are $I$ and $D$ independent?

**My Attempt**

1. Since they are both geometric distributions, we know that the expectation is $\mathbb{E}(X)=1/p$. So our parameters for $X$ and $Y$ are $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively.
   Then, we have
   $$F_X(t)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)=1-(1-\lambda)^t\quad\text{(known cdf)}$$
   $$F_Y(t)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq t)=1-(1-\mu)^t$$

Then we can make $D=min(X,Y)$. Then
$$1-F_D(t)=\mathbb{P}(D>t)=\mathbb{P}(X>t)\mathbb{P}(Y>t)=(1-\lambda)^t(1-\mu)^t$$
So our cdf is
\begin{equation}
F_D(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } t\leq0\\
(1-\lambda)^t(1-\mu)^t & \text{if } 0<t<\infty\\
1 & \text{if } t=\infty
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

2. Representing $I$ in terms of $X,Y$:
   \begin{equation}
   I=
   \begin{cases}
   0 &\text{if } X<Y\\
   1 & \text{if } X=Y\\
   2 & \text{if } X>Y
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
   $$\mathbb{P}(I=0)=\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\sum_{x\in X} \sum_{y\in Y|x<y}\mathbb{P}(x,y)$$
   Since $X,Y$ are independent
   $$\mathbb{P}(x,y)=\mathbb{P}_X(x)\mathbb{P}_Y(y)$$
   $$=[(1-\lambda)^{k-1}\lambda][(1-\mu)^{k-1}\mu]$$
   So
   $$\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\sum_{x\in X} \sum_{y\in Y|x<y}[(1-\lambda)^{k-1}\lambda][(1-\mu)^{k-1}\mu]$$
   I'm not sure how to compute $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$, but I think $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ would be similar to the case above. For a pmf, do I have to compute the sum? Or do I just leave it as it is?
3. I'd assume you'd have to find the p.m.f. for I before determining independence.

Comment: I think I made an error. I said $1-F_D(t)=(1-\lambda)^t(1-\mu)^t $, so the CDF is $F_D(t)=1-(1-\lambda)^t(1-\mu)^t $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X < Y) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X=x, Y> x)
= \sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X=x) P(Y>x)
= \sum_{x=1}^\infty [(1-\lambda)^{x-1} \lambda] (1-\mu)^x.$$
If you plug in $P(Y>k) = \sum_{y=k+1}^\infty (1-\mu)^{y-1} \mu$ to my above expression you get a double sum that resembles what you have written, but this is not necessary since you already know $P(Y>x) = 1-F_Y(x)$. But I think you got confused by your own notation (you write $k$ instead of $x$ and $y$).

You should be able to simplify the above sum using geometric series.

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty [(1-\lambda)^{x-1} \lambda] (1-\mu)^x
= \lambda(1-\mu) \sum_{x=1}^\infty [(1-\lambda)(1-\mu)]^{x-1}
= \frac{\lambda(1-\mu)}{1-(1-\lambda)(1-\mu)}$$

---

By a similar argument, $P(X > Y) = \frac{(1-\lambda)\mu}{1-(1-\lambda)(1-\mu)}$.

---

$P(X=Y)$ can be done similarly, just go through the cases $P(X=x, Y=x)$. You should get $\frac{\lambda\mu}{1-(1-\lambda)(1-\mu)}$.

---

$$P(I=0, D=d) = P(\text{no letters for $d-1$ days})P(\text{Lily but no Noah on on $d$th day})= (1-\lambda)^{d-1} (1-\mu)^{d-1} \cdot \lambda(1-\mu).$$

Check that this equals $P(I=0)P(D=d)$. Repeat for other values of $I$.